# clear input filed when clear button is pressed in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms

i have an input field in django html file and a clear button and i want to clear the input filed when the clear button is pressed. how can it be done? do i need to know javascript for that or it can be done otherway?

```html
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="textfield1" size="5">
    <input type="text" id="textfield2" size="5">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
```

i want to clear only one field not both

Comment: Without reloading the page, you will need to use some JavaScript to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a simple thing :

```
<input type="button" value="Reset" id="resetBtn" onClick="this.form.reset()" />
```

Regarding to :

```
http://javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-reset-form.phtml
```